# Does SSD improve overclocking?

Tags: performance, ssd, intel-core-i7, overclocking

Hi i just had a query in my mind-
Do i really need to add SSD to OC ...I mean does it make any difference on the perfomance of the processor ?
I would like to overclock my i7 and i have already spend much on my gpu... 
i dont care if the boot time is a bit longer.I just need the processor to deliver the speed promised by intel . ie . 4 ghz min
So is the normal Hdd okay i terms of performance ?
please help !

Comment: Having an SSD will affect the performance of the system, but will not affect your ability to overclock; they are seperate pieces of hardware.

Answer (score 2):

No, an SSD does not play any role in overclocking your CPU. Why should it? It is though a performance increase overall, not just boot time, in comparison to a HDD.

Whether the "normal HDD is okay in terms of performance" is very subjectiv. There are different kinds of HDDs in terms of performance so your question here is not very clear.

Comment: yes .. and i would take in a 7200 rpm hdd .. thanks for your suggestion mate ! cheerz ..